# Nginx Access Log: GET zc.qq.com?

Tags: nginx, web-server

I found following entry in my access.log

```
115.231.222.40 - - [02/Oct/2015:07:57:11] "GET http://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/common/attr?id=260714&r=0.8936631410048374 HTTP/1.1" 302 160 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; 360SE)"
```

What does it mean? Do I have to worry?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like a spambot trying to send an invalid request, or possibly to see if your server is misconfigured to allow proxying.

Do you have to worry?  I find it a bit strange that a `302` status code is returned, as in `302 Found`, I would expect such request to generate a `404 Not Found`, or maybe `400 Bad Request` or `403 Forbidden`, but, in general, these kinds of requests should not cause much worry with properly configured modern servers.

(In your situation, I would guess that a 302 is returned because you redirect 404 pages to a single "not found" page?  If so, then, yes, you do have to worry in regards to the usability of your site, because that's not a good practice, as the user has no chance to easily correct a mistyped URL, since it just disappears into thin air, and they'd have little clue as to what's wrong.)

Comment: I have a redirect from http to https thats why I have the 302

Comment: @fips123, that's not a good idea, either.  it means that people who don't have https, or a new-enough TLS version, won't be able to view your website.  it especially makes no sense for all those sites where all information on the site is public -- requiring mandatory encryption just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: the site is a webmail login. Everybody who should access it, can do it. so its not public.

Answer (score 3):

I'm seeing the same on a local server. The originating IP is listed as a probably bot on a Chinese ISP. It is probably part of an automated scan for a DDOS amplification attack against qq.com, which is some sort of Chinese web-mail provider. Judging by the URL there is probably a known exploit (tying up CPU-time?) against their web-server installation.

Lots of "probable" reasons, should you worry? - no, but make sure that you are not forwarding the request to the actual target domain.

Answer (score -1):

I have been getting these requests to my apache server every couple of hours on a daily basis for several months, with a differing id every time. Reports to the listed domain abuse departments for the source IP 115.230.124.164 and zc.qq.com all constantly fail.

I have deployed a rewrite rule sending all hits from the IP back to iself.